# Running PHPUnit not in command line in Win 8.1

Tags: php, windows-8, command-line, phpunit, windows-8.1

How can I running **PHPUnit** not in command line in **Win 8.1**? When I trying to run **PHPUnit**, I see this window:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't run itself **PHP** in command line of **Win 8.1** (PHP with Apache works well, in command line - no). I see the same window.

Comment: Maybe you didnt pick the right version on the website(The version for 8.1) ?^^

Comment: @Xatenev Before an last update of Win I worked with PHP in command line.